# undergraduate research experience should go for 'depth' or 'width' in terms of graduate application?

Tags: graduate-admissions, research-undergraduate

I am now going through my 3rd undergraduate year, and I am now feeling like I want to change my research direction. The current direction is yet the only direction I've dug into. But one factor is making me hesitate whether to make the move: the graduate application is less than one year away. I don't know whether changing a research direction is a wise choice at this point, i.e. I am wondering should I go for 'depth' or 'width' for my undergraduate research experience. Guys, any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you have something, than that is good enough.  You will be working on a new problem during your Ph.D. and it will be very different in the amount of time spent (full time, versus an "extracurricular").  Your grades, test scores, and letters are more important.  Nobody is expecting you to be an independent researcher at this point.  They are much more interested in scientific potential than results when rating undergrads.

I would do what you like the most. (Life is short and then...)  But if you force me to vote only based on your application, then spending more time on the initial problem and getting a publication (or more pubs) is the higher return on your time.